# Fileupload retornando o mesmo arquivo de varios selecionados

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um Fileupload que seleciono varios arquivos e vou salvando no diretorio, porem percebi que o FileBytes dele, repete igualmente em todos os arquivos.

```
if (FileUp.HasFiles)
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in FileUp.PostedFiles)
                {

                    Arquivo arq = new Arquivo();
                    ArquivoVersao arqVersao = new ArquivoVersao();
                    //seta as propriedades de arquivo

                    arq.XARQUIVO = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                    arq.EXTENSAO = Path.GetExtension(uploadedFile.FileName);

                      arq.ARQUIVOBYTE = FileUp.FileBytes;
                    FileUp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/db_arquivos/") + arq.XARQUIVO);
    } 
  }
```

aspx:

```
 <div class="modal fade open" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header" >
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text="Enviar arquivos"></asp:Label></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUp" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
                                    <br />

                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />



                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn ui-icon-cancel small" ID="UpluodButton" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" Text="Enviar" />

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Meu fileUpload é disparado aqui:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal();", true);
```

O nome, extensao, etc sempre vem certinho, porem o FileBytes sempre fica o tamanho do primeiro arquivo,Resumindo o arquivo é salvo igualmente.

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar todo o código?

Comment: @war-lock Você deveria estar buscando o tamanho do objeto uploadedFile não?

Comment: sim, mas UpluodFile nao existe o fileBytes, apenas no FIleUp, achei estranho tbm.

Comment: Editei............

Comment: postei, tem update panel, mas não no fileuplod, o Fileupload esta em um modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a propriedade InputStreamdo objeto uploadedFile, segundo a [documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) esta propriedade expõe um Stream do arquivo carregado, sendo assim, podemos usar um [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para ler os bytes do arquivo.

```
if (FileUp.HasFiles)
{
    foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in FileUp.PostedFiles)
    {
        Arquivo arq = new Arquivo();
        ArquivoVersao arqVersao = new ArquivoVersao();

        //seta as propriedades de arquivo
        arq.XARQUIVO = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
        arq.EXTENSAO = Path.GetExtension(uploadedFile.FileName);

        // Utilizando o BinaryReader para obter os bytes do objeto HttpPostedFile
        BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(uploadedFile.InputStream);
        arq.ARQUIVOBYTE = b.ReadBytes(uploadedFile.ContentLength);

        FileUp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/db_arquivos/") + arq.XARQUIVO);
    }
}
```

Comment: O tamanho nao é um inteiro?

Comment: o que eu quero é os bytes do arquivo

Comment: pra isso se usa o FileBytes, mas sempre retorna o mesmo.

Comment: da forma que vc postou da isso: Error 63 Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to 'byte[]

Comment: Eu testei, porem pra salvar. continua salvando o mesmo arquivo.

Comment: @WarLock, Cara eu errei, vc precisa é do Array de bytes, vou verificar e edito a resposta

Comment: Mas o problema nao é eu ter, e sim a parte de salvar do fileupload esta salvando o mesmo Bytes, ali onde estou setando não serve de nada.O problema é no FileUp.SaveAs.

Comment: @WarLock, alterei a resposta, utilizando o BinaryReader e a propriedade InputStream voce consegue o array de bytes do arquivo.

Comment: da isso: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int' 57

Comment: foi so colocar arq.ARQUIVOBYTE = b.ReadBytes(uploadedFile.ContentLentgth); FUncionou!

Comment: no caso o erro "Argument1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int' 57" é exibido porque o Length de InputStream é um long e voce precisa de um inteiro no parâmetro, do jeito que vc colocou irá funcionar também. De toda forma vou alterar a resposta para ficar mais claro.